# Read xml text editor file (for mac) using php & convert to array

Tags: php, xml

```
[
  {
    "ID": "50e51efe6ebef7134c0fb581",
    "Text": "A patient asks to be tested for Lyme disease.  She had been bitten by a tick and removed it herself this morning.  What is be most appropriate action?",
    "Correct": 0,
    "Answers": [
      "Disinfect the skin around the bite area and instruct the patient to return if arthralgia other concerning symptoms develop.",
      "Advise the patient to return in 4-6 weeks, when testing will yield reliable results",
      "Refer the patient to a physician for a precautionary administration of antibiotics",
      "Obtain a blood sample for immediate testing"
    ],
    "Media": "",
    "Explanation": "Lyme disease is difficult to detect, especially so soon after a tick bite and in the absense of symptoms.  The patient should return after some time if arthralgia or other symptoms develop.  "
  },
  {
    "ID": "50e51efe6ebef7134c0fb582",
    "Text": "Which of the following is part of a standard treatment plan for a diagnosis of stage I Lyme disease?",
    "Correct": 0,
    "Answers": [
      "A topical antihistamine to reduce symptoms",
      "No treatment unless the disease progresses to stage II or stage III",
      "Administration of oral antibiotics",
      "Administration of intravenous antibiotics"
    ],
    "Media": "",
    "Explanation": "Stage I is called Early Localized Lyme Disease. The infection is not yet widespread throughout the body.  This is treated with a topical antihistamine to reduce itching and swelling."
  }
]
```

Comment: What is the question and where is your XML?

Comment: The above code is the file which I have in .txt format. I want to read it using PHP to insert into database

Comment: But that's JSON and not XML.

Comment: If it is JSON and it is in a file let say db.txt and I want to read it using PHP. It is basically question with 3 or 4 answers.

Comment: So you have a file with JSON data in it. You want to read it and convert the JSON structure to a PHP array. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. Want to convert it to array of PHP

Comment: Did you try something already?

Comment: Yes I read the file but it display it as one unit or whole file not break down.